# Terminal will not open new window on startup with Sierra

Tags: terminal, macos

After upgrading to macOS Sierra, Terminal no longer opens with a new window on startup despite having the preference enabled. I have to click on the dock icon to open a new window. Is there a way to make Terminal honor the preference setting?

Here is a screenshot of my preferences
[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot of the preference setting?

Comment: @DenisRasulev Added screenshot to the question.

Comment: Well... Just to make sure that we are on the same ground. By "startup" we understand startup of the terminal *application*, not the startup of the *computer*, right?

Comment: Yes, the startup of terminal